# How many even numbers can you form which are greater than 100 subject to the following constraints?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 3 digit even numbers can be made from the numbers 0,1,2,3 which are greater than 100.

The book answer says 20 but I am getting 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

As a first approximation there are $3$ choices for the first digit, $4$ choices for the second digit, and $2$ choices for the last digit, since it must be $0$ or $2$. That’s a total of $3\cdot4\cdot2$ numbers. However, one of those is $100$, which has to be excluded, so there are only $23$.

**Added:** And indeed the numbers involved are small enough to permit direct verification:

$$\begin{align*}
&102,110,112,120,122,130,132,\\
&200,202,210,212,220,222,230,232,\\
&300,302,310,312,320,322,330,332
\end{align*}$$

Comment: The stupid book.!

Comment: @user81416: It happens. In fact in my experience it happens more often answers sections than in the rest of the book.